# Parsing XML in iphone using NSXML parser

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsxmlparser

I am new to iphone.I have this xml Response.How can i  parse it using NSXML Parser?

```
<MyList>
    <Emp>
      <EmpId>918704ec-4811-45b6-a169-16bae3df3452</EmpId>
    </Emp>
     <Emp>
       <Details>
          <Name>Ravi</Name>
          <EmpId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000</EmpId>
       </Details>
          <EmpId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000</EmpId>
    </Emp>

</MyList>
```

From this I want the values of EmpId(918704ec-4811-45b6-a169-16bae3df3452) and Name(Ravi).I dont want EmpId(00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000)
Parsing code is :

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"List"]) 
{
    arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    drr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 

}
srr=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
} 


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{


[srr appendString:string];
}
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"EmpId"])
{

    [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"EmpId"];
    [srr release],srr=nil;
    return;
}    

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"])
{

    [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"Name"];
    [srr release],srr=nil;
    [arr addObject:drr]; 

    return;
} 

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"MyList"])
{
   [drr release];

 }

[srr release],srr=nil;

 }
```

I need response to be like this:

```
  (
  {
   Name="Ravi";
   Id="918704ec-4811-45b6-a169-16bae3df3452";
  }
  )
```

Comment: That's some awful XML document you have as your datasource....

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/) is a link where you can convert the XML to NSDictionary form it contains two file XMLReader.h and XMLReader.m you need to add in your project and using the code in code where you need it in this form

```
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:testXMLString error:&parseError];

// Print the dictionary
NSLog(@"%@", xmlDictionary);
```

Hope this will help you